# Loss of cookies in Internet Explorer

Tags: asp.net, cookies

I am developing the website which is integrated with the other one. By pressing a certain button you are being redirected to the second website, and the address of the website you came from is being saved in the cookies. Another button will redirect you back. Everything works fine in Chrome.

The problem is that Internet Explorer recognizes the first site as a part of local intranet and the second as a part of the internet which leads to loss of cookies.

So I have a couple of questions about that:

1) what can I do with this (including the second site in the local intranet zone is not an option)

2) what is the best practice to that problem in general?

Comment: Which site saves which cookie?

Comment: The first site saves cookie, and the second one uses it.

Comment: Usually, a website is not supposed to access cookies saved by a different site. What does the cookie look like?

Comment: Just the session ID and link to page from which user came

Comment: The acutal question is "why does it seem to work in chrome?"... Your second application could check the referrer and save it itself. 
Please post the actual cookie data. Are the apps on different domains?